# Summing sequentially in excel and ensuring it never dips below 0

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Say if I have a column of positive and negative integers,

`120
100
-60
-240
-100
50`

How would I sum so that the `-240` is ignored because that would result in a negative sum at that point when summing from top to bottom?

Comment: Just to clarify, you'd want the SUM value to be 110?

Comment: more general: you want to keep removing the negative values starting with the biggest until the sum is positiv?

Comment: @MichaelFrank yep sorry should have stayed that

Comment: @Albin I want to be able to determine at what point in the sequence the sum dips below 0 if possible

Comment: sorry, I don't really understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I put your values in A2:A7.

In cell B2, your formula is `=A2`, since you have no second value to sum.

In cell B3, your formula will be `=IF(SUM(B2,A3)>0,SUM(B2,A3),B2)`. This checks to see if adding the next number in your list will keep the sum positive. If the sum goes negative, that value won't get added, and the cumulative sum stays the same as the previous row. Drag this formula down the column.

You wanted to see at what point the value dips below 0, so in Column C, your formula is `=0` for Cell C2. For Cell C3, your formula will be `=IF(SUM(B2,A3)<0,1,0)`. This says "if I add this value to my cumulative sum and the sum goes negative, make the cell value 1, otherwise make it 0." Drag this formula down the column. I then added conditional formatting to column C so that any cell whose value is 1 turns red, and those that are 0 are green. Red rows are your dips.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the source occupies A1:A6. Insert formulas:

```
B1=A1
B2=IF(B1+A2<0,B1,B1+A2)
```

Drag down B2 till B6.

To find where the value was skipped you can use conditional formatting on B2:B6=B1:B5.